# TypeScriptでのUNIX時間取得

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptでUNIX時間を取得したく、以下のようにすると、

```
var unixtime = new Date / 1000;
```

以下のようなコンパイルエラーになります。

> error TS2113: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

どのように実装すれば回避できるでしょうか。

Comment: 頂いた回答意外に以下の書き方もできるようなので追記しておきます
```var x = +new Date / 1000;
var x = Date.now() / 1000;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScriptの範囲ですが、

```
var unixtime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！基本的なところでお恥ずかしいmm

Comment: @hidechae いえ、気軽に暇人にデバッグさせればいいのです。あと解決したのでしたら回答にチェックマークをつけていただけると嬉しいです。